HTTP-triggered Azure Function runs quickly when manually triggered, but times out with Azure Logic Apps HTTP
I get this error when invoking my Azure Function using Azure Logic Apps HTTP action:

Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits.

I know that there is a 230-second limit to wait for the function to respond. However, when triggering using Python, the function returns an output in ~150 seconds.
url = 'XXX' # Azure Function url
data = {
  "Connect-Type": "application/json"
}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

Does anyone know what could be going wrong? Or is there a way to make the function "respond" within the limit, and continue running?

Can you share the screenshot of the logic app workflow? I would like to see how you are invoking the python function in logic app. Are you using v2 model?

Also, please share your function code

I am able to get the expected output while invoking the url of v2 default function in HTTP action

The timeout duration for Consumption (multitenant) Logic Apps is 120 seconds, not 235, therefore it is logical that you are getting a timeout if your function responds only in ~150 seconds.
